# Passing a std::shared_ptr<T> to a function that takes a std::shared_ptr<const T>?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, shared-ptr

I have a function that needs to take shared ownership of an argument, but does not modify it.
I have made the argument a shared_ptr<const T> to clearly convey this intent.

```
template <typename T>
void func(std::shared_ptr<const T> ptr){}
```

I would like to call this function with a shared_ptr to a non-const T. For example:

```
auto nonConstInt = std::make_shared<int>();
func(nonConstInt);
```

However this generates a compile error on VC 2017:

```
error C2672: 'func': no matching overloaded function found
error C2784: 'void func(std::shared_ptr<const _Ty>)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::shared_ptr<const _Ty>' from 'std::shared_ptr<int>'
note: see declaration of 'func'
```

Is there a way to make this work without:

- Modifying the calls to func.  This is part of a larger code refactoring, and I would prefer not to have to use std::const_pointer_cast at every call site.
- Defining multiple overloads of func as that seems redundant.

We are currently compiling against the C++14 standard, with plans to move to c++17 soon, if that helps.

Comment: I think templates are taking higher preference, if this would be fully typed it works. You could add an overload, though that doesn't make a lot of sense. Just to be sure, you need a shared_ptr here instead of a reference?

Comment: Yes, it works if func is not a template (which is why I was surprised it didn't work for templated functions). func is taking shared ownership of the pointed to object, so I can't take a reference to T.

Comment: Goh, foresee a free method to add the const to the shared_ptr would be my pragmatic solution, or add the 2 overloads and explicitly add the const before redirecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.

I ended up solving this a slightly different way. I changed the function parameter to just a `shared_ptr` to any `T` so that it would allow const types, then I used `std::enable_if` to restrict the template to types that I care about. (In my case `vector<T>` and `const vector<T>`)

The call sites don't need to be modified. The function will compile when called with both `shared_ptr<const T>` and `shared_ptr<T>` without needing separate overloads.

Here's a complete example that compiles on VC, GCC, and clang:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct is_vector : public std::false_type{};

template<typename T>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T>> : public std::true_type{};

template<typename T>
struct is_vector<const std::vector<T>> : public std::true_type{};

template <typename ArrayType,
         typename std::enable_if_t<is_vector<ArrayType>::value>* = nullptr>
void func( std::shared_ptr<ArrayType> ptr) {
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr< const std::vector<int> > constPtr;
    std::shared_ptr< std::vector<int> > nonConstPtr;
    func(constPtr);
    func(nonConstPtr);
}
```

The only downside is that the non-const instantiation of `func` will allow non-const methods to be called on the passed-in ptr. In my case a compile error will still be generated since there are some calls to the const version of `func` and both versions come from the same template.

Answer (score 5):

```
template <typename T>
void cfunc(std::shared_ptr<const T> ptr){
  // implementation
}
template <typename T>
void func(std::shared_ptr<T> ptr){ return cfunc<T>(std::move(ptr)); }
template <typename T>
void func(std::shared_ptr<const T> ptr){ return cfunc<T>(std::move(ptr)); }
```

this matches how `cbegin` works, and the "overloads" are trivial forwarders with nearly zero cost.

Comment: Hm. And here I thought `cbegin()` generally delegates to `begin()`.

Comment: Why not... `std::shared_ptr<const T> lp = std::move(ptr);` as the first line in func()?

Comment: Even though [your suggestion works](https://godbolt.org/z/59b3G9occ) it can also be done [with a single delegating function](https://godbolt.org/z/1fqGbEsxY) is there any advantage for the two delegating functions?

Comment: @AmirKirsh No, not that I can think of.  Other than seeing the `const` in the signature of `func`, which could help with code assist tools.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no good solution to what you desire. The error occurs because it fails to deduce template argument `T`. During argument deduction it attempts only a few simple conversations and you cannot influence it in any way.

Think of it: to cast from `std::shared_ptr<T>` to some `std::shared_ptr<const U>` it requires to know `U`, so how should compiler be able to tell that `U=T` and not some other type? You can always cast to `std::shared_ptr<const void>`, so why not `U=void`? So such searches aren't performed at all as in general it is not solvable. Perhaps, hypothetically one could propose a feature where certain user-explicitly-declared casts are attempted for argument deduction but it isn't a part of C++.

Only advise is to write function declaration without `const`:

```
    template <typename T>
    void func(std::shared_ptr<T> ptr){}
```

You could try to show your intent by making the function into a redirection like:

```
    template <typename T>
    void func(std::shared_ptr<T> ptr)
    {
           func_impl<T>(std::move(ptr));
    }
```

Where `func_impl` is the implementation function that accepts a `std::shared_ptr<const T>`. Or even perform const cast directly upon calling `func_impl`.

Answer (score 0):

As the `const` is *only* for documentation, make it a comment:

```
template <class T>
void func(std::shared_ptr</*const*/ T> p) {
}
```

You could additionally delegate to the version getting a pointer to constant object if the function is hefty enough to make it worthwhile:

```
template <class T>
void func(std::shared_ptr</*const*/ T> p) {
    if (!std::is_const<T>::value) // TODO: constexpr
        return func<const T>(std::move(p));
}
```

No guarantee the compiler will eliminate the move though.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't want to be modifying the call sites, but you sure can be modifying the functions themselves - that's what you implied in the question anyway. Something had to be changed *somewhere*, after all.

Thus:

In C++17 you could use deduction guides and modify call sites, but in a less intrusive manner than with a cast. I'm sure a language lawyer can pitch in about whether adding a deduction guide to the `std` namespace is allowed. At the very least we can limit the applicability of those deduction guides to the types we care about - it won't work for the others. That's to limit potential for mayhem.

```
template <typename T>
class allow_const_shared_ptr_cast : public std::integral_constant<bool, false> {};
template <typename T>
static constexpr bool allow_const_shared_ptr_cast_v = allow_const_shared_ptr_cast<T>::value;

template<>
class allow_const_shared_ptr_cast<int> : public std::integral_constant<bool, true> {};

template <typename T>
void func(std::shared_ptr<const T> ptr) {}

namespace std {
template<class Y> shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>&) noexcept 
    -> shared_ptr<std::enable_if_t<allow_const_shared_ptr_cast_v<Y>, const Y>>;
template<class Y> shared_ptr(shared_ptr<Y>&&) noexcept
    -> shared_ptr<std::enable_if_t<allow_const_shared_ptr_cast_v<Y>, const Y>>;
}

void test() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> nonConstInt;
    func(std::shared_ptr(nonConstInt));
    func(std::shared_ptr(std::make_shared<int>()));
}
```

`std::shared_ptr` is certainly less wordy than `std::const_pointer_cast<SomeType>`.

This should not have any performance impact, but sure modifying the call sites is a pain.

Otherwise there's no solution that doesn't involve modifying the called function declarations - but the modification should be acceptable, I think, since it's not any more wordy than what you had already:

Comment: Yes, adding it to `::std` is forbidden.Still, what about adding `volatile` and `const volatile` variants?